# Shrinking a volume and extending another in dynamic disk

Tags: windows-server-2008, storage, hard-drive

I have a test environment where I converted a disk to dynamic, shrunk a volume, and then expanded another all on the same disk. The result is that disk management in Windows Server 2008 R2 shows two separate partitions in the volume, `Backup (G:) 6.21 GB NTFS` and `Backup (G:) 30.74 GB NTFS`. Is this functioning as designed and what is the reason for this? In the past on a basic disk shrinking a volume and extending another would add the shrank and unformatted volume to the same "selection" for the disk, but now they are separate yet add up to the same amount of storage on the partition. Is this because the extended space on the original partition is logical in nature?

[image: Disk Management screenshot]

Comment: I just noticed that in the list of volumes in the top that the two partitions don't add up to 36GB in the screenshot, but they did after I refreshed. The partitions are still separate though, in disk management.

Comment: One of the sys admins at work said that it will join into the original volume on the disk if the unallocated space appears at the end of the sections to the right of Disk 1, which makes complete sense to me so I'm wondering why it just didn't go to the end. I'm assuming because the list of volumes to the right of a physical disk "reflect" where data is written on the physical drive, from the inside of the drive to the outside of the drive the further you go right.